# Transform a pose to another frame with tf2 in Python

Tags: python, pose, posestamped, tf2, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pose stamped given in camera frame. Now I want to transform the pose to get its coordinates in the base_link frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222306/transform-a-pose-to-another-frame-with-tf2-in-python/) by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2756 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Import the needed modules:

```
import tf2_ros
import tf2_geometry_msgs
```

Initialize the tf buffer and listener somewhere in your init function:

```
tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(rospy.Duration(100.0))  # tf buffer length
tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer)
```

Do the actual transformation:

```
transform = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame,
                                       # source frame:
                                       pose_stamped.header.frame_id,
                                       # get the tf at the time the pose was valid
                                       pose_stamped.header.stamp,
                                       # wait for at most 1 second for transform, otherwise throw
                                       rospy.Duration(1.0))

pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_pose(pose_stamped, transform)
```

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2016-03-22**:
The lookup should better be wrapped inside a try-except block in case the transform is not found: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29#The_Code_Explained